# Short story about boy who can see the future end of the world, lies for the good of humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is at least 35 or so years old. It's about a boy who can foresee the future, I think by a couple of days. He has a radio or a TV show where he'll tell the future about lost hikers being found, etc. 
   He then has a vision that the world is going to end in catastrophe. He is wracked by the decision of what to report to the people, and winds up telling his audience he has good news: humanity is going to enter a golden age. He alone has the knowledge of the end of the world, but knowing the info would cause panic, chooses to give the world hope.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the short story [The Boy Who Predicted Earthquakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Predicted_Earthquakes) by Margaret St. Clair. It was first published in 1950. You may have also seen the Rod Serling's Night Gallery episode.

He has a radio or a TV show where he'll tell the future about lost hikers being found, etc.

> "Herbie's broadcast generates a sensational global response, as his predictions are rebroadcast around the world and millions of viewers have become convinced that he can accurately read the future. The boy and an unnamed narrator, pursued by ecstatic fans, are forced to take refuge in a skyscraper hotel located near the broadcasting studio. The rejoicing crowds cheer Herbie from far below; close to the top of the building, all he and the narrator can see are sun and sky. "

The key point that matches is that that the boy in question ends up lying about the sun going nova to prevent a panic.

> Herbie reports that he has seen a scene enacted in the near future which he could not understand until his childhood research in astronomy has explained it to him: he has learned about something called a "nova." What he has really seen, and had not wanted to tell his audience, was that "tomorrow – the sun is going to explode."

Comment: Beichst, that was magic. Thank you! I'm going to check out the Serling version now, as well as some other works by the author. You're allowing me to revisit a story from my childhood.